# update model angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand how AngularJS works.
I have a directive `count-Date` that calculates age by month and year.
I can not directly write to the data model, because I have a lot of fields, but I want to use my code multiple time.

HTML:

```
<div>Date of birth first child
    month:  <input type = "text" id = "MonthFirstChild" ng-model='MonthFirstChild' required          maxlength="2" only-Digits month required count-Date>   
    year: <input type = "text" name='YearFirstChild' ng-model='YearFirstChild' maxlength="4" only-Digits  year-Of-Birth required count-Date>
   <span ng-model = "AgeFirstChild">{{AgeFirstChild}}</span>
</div>

<div>Date of birth second child
    month:  <input type = "text" id = "MonthSecondChild" ng-model='MonthSecondChild' required maxlength="2" only-Digits month required count-Date>  
    year: <input type = "text" name='YearSecondChild' ng-model='YearSecondChild' maxlength="4" only-Digits  year-Of-Birth required count-Date>
   <span ng-model = "AgeSecondChild">{{AgeSecondChild}}</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('countDate', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('blur', function(event,el) {
                var el = angular.element(element),
                    month = +el.parent().children().eq(0).val(),
                    year = +el.parent().children().eq(1).val(),
                    dateOfBirth = new Date(year,month),
                    now = new Date(),
                    today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()),
                    age = Math.round((now - dateOfBirth)/(32140800000);                                       
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I need help in rewriting the directive.

Comment: Could you post your directive source for count-date and maybe some specifics about exactly what it is that you're having trouble with? Specific questions get specific answers ;)

Comment: @AbrahamP I added the directive. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: and what are you expecting this directive to do that it isn't doing? What is it SPECIFICALLY that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @AbrahamP I want to record the calculated year in span AgeFirstChild and AgeSecondChild respectively. But I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer. Out of curiosity, what does = + do? I've never seen that syntax...

Comment: + is a cast to number. @AbrahamP

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is calculate the age, writing a directive is a bit of an overkill - you can simply write a scope method calculating the age, something like:

HTML:

```
<div>Date of birth first child
    month: <input type="number" min="1" max="12" ng-model="MonthFirstChild" required maxlength="2" />   
    year: <input type="number" min="0" max="9999" ng-model="YearFirstChild" required maxlength="4" />   
    <span>{{getAge(YearFirstChild, MonthFirstChild)}}</span>
</div>
```

JS (controller):

```
$scope.getAge = function(year,month) {
    var dateOfBirth = new Date(year, month),
        now = new Date();
    return now.getFullYear() - dateOfBirth.getFullYear();
};
```

Comment: I do not understand when I need to use a directive or method.Please advise me what to read for understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

I would use an `ng-repeat` to iterate over a collection of children.

The parent scope:

```
   app.controller('wrapperController', ['$scope', function(scope){
     scope.children = [{
       name: 'John'
     }
     ,{
      name: 'Bill'
     }
     ,{
      name: 'Bob'
     }];  
   }]);
```

Now I am going to go out on a limb and guess that in your real application you have some sort of dynamic datasource for children, but lets assume its hardcoded.

What we can then do is wrap the entire template as html, lets say the following is in a file `child.html`:

```
<count-date date-container="child">Date of birth of child:
  month:<input type = "text" ng-model='dateContainer.month' required maxlength="2">
  year: <input type = "text"  ng-model='dateContainer.year' maxlength="4">
  <span>{{child.age}}</span>
  <br>
 </count-date>
```

and let us say we have the two following directives:

```
    angular.module('demo').directive('child', [function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: './child.html'
  }  
}]);

angular.module('demo').directive('countDate', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        dateContainer: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('dateContainer.month', function(newVal, oldVal){
          if(newVal && scope.dateContainer.year){
            scope.dateContainer.age = Math.round((new Date() - new Date(JSON.parse(scope.dateContainer.year), JSON.parse(newVal)))/32140800000);  

          }
        });
        scope.$watch('dateContainer.year', function(newVal, oldVal){
          if(newVal && scope.dateContainer.month){
            scope.dateContainer.age = Math.round((new Date() - new Date(JSON.parse(newVal), JSON.parse(scope.dateContainer.month)))/32140800000);  
          }

        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3tnQEnnm7DQbbn0yIEbe?p=preview

This will work and do what (I believe) you want. Lets talk about how and why it works:

1) We store an array of all our children. this allows us to use `ng-repeat` to iterate over them in a repeatable manner

2) We pass each child into a bidirectional binding on an isolate scope in our count-date directive. This means that the directive will create its own scope which DOES NOT inherit from any parent scope. This is to allow ease of reuse on the directive. However, by passing a bidirectional binding into the scope declaration with the `=`, we bind to a variable in the parent (controller) scope. Thus, when we modify the `dateContainer` on the `count-date` the variable it was originally bound down from (in our case `child`) is also modified. Similiarly if one of the parents modifies `child`, this will also affect `dateContainer`. Since `ng-repeat` also binds to the object it is iterating over by reference, any changes will propagate all the way through the stack.

3) By setting an `ng-model` on `child.year` and `child.month` rather then `month` or `year`, we ensure that the fields are being added to the existing object, and as such will be available in all scopes. If we had bound `ng-model` to `year` we would have instantiated that variable only within the innermost isolate scope, and none of our parents would have received this new data.

4) We `$watch` the attributes of child that we want. What this means is that whenever the two attributes (`dataContainer.month` or `dataContainer.year`) change, they run the callbacks provided (calculating age), and then trigger a `$digest` iteration, forcing a rerender of {{child.age}}